# Four temperature SHT31 sensors on ESP32

Tags: i2c, esp32

I have to read out the teperature and humidity of four independent SHT31 sensors with the help of an ESP32. Is there any prefered way to do this, since the only examples I can find online are only with one sensor. I have no access to the address pins of the sensors.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem ... I am trying to use four SHT31 sensors in a ESP32. I have tried to use the multiplexer with those, but because I am using an I2C extender I could not connected. Thanks for your help and guideline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using TS3A5018, part from TI.
You can then connect 4 independent I2C devices (SHT31).

There are also dedicated I2C channel multiplexers such as these. [image]

Below is the example for I2C multiplexer from TI

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, reading 4 SHT31 is possible with an ESP32.

If you have the analog version, readout is quite trivial: you simply use 8 analog inputs (2 for each) to read the signal.

If you have the digital version, which has an I2C interface, you need to control each sensor's address pin separately to select the specific sensor you want to read. Otherwise, there will be an address collision on the bus.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is, that I have no access to the address pins

Comment: @zet0 Then you need to get I2C bus multiplexers, to get each chip on its own bus lines